# JQuery DataTables - showing Page Length option as well as Export Buttons

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using DataTables and I want to show Page Length option on the Left side Export Buttons in the Center and Search/Field on the Right side at the top of the table as well as at the bottom of the table above Pagination.

My problem is that when I add feature to show Export buttons they do not show at all and if I use dom: "Bfrtip" then the Page Length option is getting removed.

I am using following JS of DataTable:

```
$("#member_list").DataTable({
    scrollY: "800px",   //Remove this if we do now want to show Verticle Scroll Bar
    scrollX: !0,    //Remove this if we do now want to show Horizontal Scroll Bar
    stateSave: !0,  //Use to save State of current Pagination when page is refreshed
    language: {
        paginate: {
            previous: "<i class='mdi mdi-chevron-left'>",
            next: "<i class='mdi mdi-chevron-right'>"
        }
    },
    drawCallback: function() {
        $(".dataTables_paginate > .pagination").addClass("pagination-rounded")
    },
    columnDefs: [{
        orderable: false,
        targets: [2,3,4,5]  //Here we disable sorting fearure for few cols
    }],
    
    buttons: [
        'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
    ]
});
```

I am using following HTML Table structure:
<

```
table id="member_list" class="table" class="table table-striped dt-responsive nowrap w-100">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th data-toggle="true">Action</th>
    <th>M Code</th>
    <th>M Name</th>
    <th>MM Branch</th>
    <th>MM Code</th>
    <th>Member Name</th>
    <th>Mobile</th>
    <th>DOB</th>
    <th data-hide="phone, tablet">M Reg Date</th>
    <th data-hide="phone, tablet">M Fees</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody id="tbody">

</tbody>
</table>
```

Here TBody is appended using Ajax.
Please help solve this problem.

I made changes as per Andrew's suggestion and now I am getting the buttons in the middle/center.

But the buttons are coming up all stuck to each other without any spacing between them.
[image]

Any solution for this problem would be great.

TIA

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option for this, with help from some CSS.

The CSS, which I added to my test page `<head>`, in a `<style>` section:

```
div.dt-top-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}

div.dt-center-in-div {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

div.dt-filter-spacer {
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

The `dom` option is this:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
  dom: '<"dt-top-container"<l><"dt-center-in-div"B><f>r>t<"dt-filter-spacer"f><ip>',
  buttons: [ 'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print' ]
} );
```

The end result is:

[image]

This works by wrapping the relevant DataTable elements in their own divs, using `<...>` and also adding class names, where needed, using "class-name".

Using a CSS `grid` is a simple way to space out the top 3 controls (page length, buttons, filter box).

For the footer section, I just place the filterbox in its own div.

You can re-arrange the DOM elements to fit your needs, if the above is not exactly what you want. And you can fine-tune the results by adjusting the CSS.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. This works really very well.

Comment: After implementing your solution I observed that all the buttons are sticking togather with each other and this is looking odd. I tried to separate them but could not achieve this. Can you guide me as to how to space them out.

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide a screenshot, or describe how to recreate what you are seeing? I am not sure what "sticking together" means - or what you would prefer the behavior to be, instead.

Comment: Andrew, I have edited my question and added a screen shot of what I am getting. Please check and help me if you can.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification - now I see what you mean. The "stuck" buttons are almost certainly related to the CSS you are using (which may be part of a framework such as Angular, if you are using a framework). I don't have your CSS, so it's not something I can help with. The best suggestion I have is: (1) Create a JS Fiddle, so people can see the problem for themselves; (2) Open a new question showing the problem, and containing a link to the Fiddle. I expect you need to add `padding-left` and `padding-right` values to the relevant CSS style - but that is a guess.