# How to rearrange DataTables controls

Tags: jquery, datatables

Hi I want to rearrange the positions of elements of datatables and also want to add one button

I tried following code

```
  $('#tblLocations').DataTable({
            scrollY: '45vh',
            targets: 'no-sort',
            bSort: true,
            order: [],
            columnDefs: [
                { orderable: false, targets: -1 },
                { "className": "dt-center", "targets": "_all" }
            ],
            "dom": 'l <"pull-right"f> <"toolbar"> tip'
        });
        $("div.toolbar").html("<button class=\"btn btn-info\" onclick=\"metroDialog.open('#AddLocationModel')\">Add Location</button>");
        activateMenuButton("btn_locations");
    }

});
```

}

but the output is of above code is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gPap.png)

but I want the output to be like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsAoZ.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the DataTables `dom` option, as you do, is a good approach.

You can use a solution similar to the one shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66155936/12567365), but with some differences.

The solution:

I use these CSS styles:

```
div.dt-top-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
}

div.dt-center-in-div {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

div.dt-btn-container {
  margin: 0 0 0 auto;
}
```

I use the `dom` option as follows:

```
dom: '<"dt-top-container"<l><"dt-center-in-div"f><"dt-btn-container"B>r>tip',
```

This places the three controls above the table into three separate divs. There is also a surrounding div which controls the grid layout for these divs.

The styles then ensure the left/center/right spacing for the controls.

Note that this uses the `B` option which is for DataTables buttons. But the good news here is: You do not need to import any of the DataTables buttons libraries. Just using the `B` is a convenient way to give us that third (empty) div on the right hand side, into which we can then place our custom button (similar to your approach):

```
$("div.dt-btn-container").html("<button class=\"btn btn-info\" onclick=\"metroDialog.open('#AddLocationModel')\">Add Location</button>");
```

The end result looks like this:

[image]