# How to add an element after the search field in DataTables?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatables

I want to add an extra element in the same row just after the search field in a DataTable.

The extra element is just a button which is supposed to call another function to do an other task.

Can anyone help me out to do this?

```
 <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Filière</th>
                    <th>Niveau</th>
                    <th>Période</th>
                    <th>Matière</th>
                    <th>Natude de la charge</th>
                    <th>Unité de volume</th>
                    <th>Volume</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
               
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

-- Javascript --

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $("#example").one("preInit.dt", function () {

    $button = $("<a><svg xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" width=\"35\" height=\"35\" fill=\"#426DC4\" class=\"bi bi-plus-square-fill pl-1\" viewBox=\"0 1 16 16\"><path d=\"M2 0a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H2zm6.5 4.5v3h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-3v3a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-3h-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3v-3a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0z\" /></svg ></a>");
    $("#example_filter label").append($button);
    $button.button();

  });
  $('#example').DataTable();
 });;
```

Comment: i have added my code to the question , thanks in advance

Comment: as you can see in the javascript function that code just add an extra button to the search label , but i wanna it to be idependent from the search label

Comment: Here is a similar question: [How to rearrange DataTables controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66689689/how-to-rearrange-datatables-controls). My suggested approach uses the DataTables `dom` option, with a CSS grid. You can customize the grid to adjust the layout.

Comment: thank you @andrewjames this is what i am looking for i will try to apply this one