# DataTables - controls rendering does not work a expected

Tags: datatables, bootstrap-5

Rendering of controls are not ok. I am using:

```
jquery 3.3.1
bootstrap 5.1.2
DataTables 1.13.2
```

To better use control, I am using:

```
var MDT=$('#myTable').DataTable({

    dom: "<'row'<'col'l><'col'f>>" +
    "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
    "<'row'<'col'i><'col'p>>",
    autoWidth:true,
    responsive: true,
    scrollX: true,
```

The result in html is not as I expected:

[image]

The elements should take the whole space and not wrap texts. The same is for search field ("cerca" in Italian).

[image]

Expected layout is with search and show on the same line, like here :

[image: expected layout]

Comment: Take a look at the approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66155936/12567365). In your case, you do not need to populate the middle section - so you can leave it empty or just adjust the CSS and remove it completely. Does that help? (It does not use Bootstrap style classes.)

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

I was missing che specific dataTables css for bootstrap:

Now it works